# Find the cosets in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]/Q_1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Find the cosets in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]/Q_1$ where $Q_1=\{3a+(1+\sqrt{-5})b|a,b\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]\}$. I am studying this and am having trouble understanding how to find cosets of quotient rings. I understand that it means the congruence classes modulo $Q_1$ and I know in this case there should be 3 distinct cosets. But how do I find the cosets? Please explain how you found them. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the ring isomorphism $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^2+5)}\cong \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ which comes from the evaluation homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $p(x)\mapsto p(\sqrt{-5})$. Now, consider the preimage of the ideal $Q_1=(3,1+\sqrt{-5})$ under the isomorphism $\bar{f}:\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^2+5)}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ induced by $f$ above. This, in turn, induces an isomorphism $$\frac{\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^2+5)}}{f^{-1}(Q_1)}\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]}{(3,1+\sqrt{-5})}.$$ Now, you can check that $f^{-1}(Q_1)=\frac{(3,1+x,x^2+5)}{(x^2+5)}$. Hence, by one of the isomorphism theorems you have $$\frac{\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^2+5)}}{\frac{(3,\,1+x,\,x^2+5)}{(x^2+5)}}\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(3,1+x,x^2+5)}\cong \frac{\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(3)}}{\frac{(3,1+x,x^2+5)}{(3)}}\cong \frac{\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{3\mathbb{Z}}[x]}{(1+x)},$$ where in the last isomorphism, it is used that $x^2+5=x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$ in $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{3\mathbb{Z}}[x]$. Clearly, the last ring is the field with 3 elements. Therefore, if you keep track of the cosets under the isomorphisms above, you can see an explicit description of your cosets in the original ring.

Comment: Op wants to the find the **cosets**.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise
$$\Bbb{Z}+(1+\sqrt{-5})\Bbb{Z} =\bigcup_{a=0}^2 a+ 3\Bbb{Z}+(1+\sqrt{-5})\Bbb{Z}$$
(disjoint union)

then show that $Q_1=3\Bbb{Z}+(1+\sqrt{-5})\Bbb{Z}$